# I have rotated the imageButton layout but i don't want to rotate the icon of the imageButton in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on android application and I have Constraint Layout. Inside that layout I have an ImageButton and I've rotated the imageButton at 45 angle, but i don't want to rotate the icon of the imageButton that has placed in it and showing as a drawable resource. Can anybody please help me to which property should i use in xml that cause my desire results.

```html
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibImage"
    android:layout_width="93dp"
    android:layout_height="93dp"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:layout_marginLeft="122dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon" />
```